# Поиск объекта и дальнейшее слежение за ним на экране. Python

Tags: python, бот

Делаю бота для игры, встретил капчу где нужно проследить за наперстком. Сидел везде где можно, но так и не нашёл способа это сделать, видел как делается на других языках, думаю на Python'е это тоже осуществимо. Буду рад если кто-то подскажет как и в каком направлении искать.

Comment: Компьютерное зрение? `OpenCV`? Думаю, это будет крайне сложно.

Comment: Только openCV или есть еще способы? Просто сколько не искал находил только отслеживание объектов окружения через openCV